# Continue pipeline after WebSocketServerProtocolHandler when no upgrade specified?

Tags: websocket, netty

I have `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler` handler on the root path, where I also accept regular HTTP requests. However, `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler` wont let me use my HTTP request, as it assumes everything is web sockets and responds with:

```
not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade
```

Can I simply continue execution of the pipeline after `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler` when upgrade to web sockets is not required? In other words, I need both HTTP and WebSockets operate on same address.

Yeah, I could probably copy/paste and do my own `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler`, but is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc for [WebSocketServerProtocolHander](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.html) refers you to the io.netty.example.http.websocketx.html5.WebSocketServer example. However it might not be entirely obvious what's happening here.

If you take a look at the source code for [WebSocketServerInitializer](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerInitializer.html) you can see that by default it sets up a fairly standard HTTP pipeline. This is because, as you know, the upgrade request is a HTTP request. The magic happens in the handleHttpRequest method of [WebSocketServerHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerHandler.html). It falls through to line 96 and assumes it's an upgrade request (you might want to actually check). It creates a WebSocketServerHandshaker and starts the handshake. The trick is that it automatically reconfigures the pipeline to handle web socket traffic so you don't have to. Take a look at the handshake method in [WebSocketServerHandshaker](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketServerHandshaker.html) to see what's going on.

Comment: The behavior changed significantly in Netty 4.0.35 ([commit](https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/2e6544fc0e2581f96652be02d86e777e8e0493bc)) - since then, the WebSocketServerProtocolHandler initiates a handshake only for the websocket path (not all paths).  Be sure to look at the appropriate revision of the example code.